# Android retrofit converter exception

Tags: android, json, exception, retrofit

**How to format/design your class if you can get 2 different response request from the server?**

Note: Retrofit will thrown an Exception if the JSON response format (design) is different with your class. All fields from JSON response must be present in your class.

**Java class, like JSON response:**

```
public class RequestResponseLogin
{
   public ResponseLogin status;

   public class ResponseLogin
   {
      public boolean success;
      public List<String> message;
   }
}
```

**The JSON response:**

```
{
    "status" : {
                    "success" : false
                    "message" : {
                                    "Invalid credientials",
                                    "....",
                                    "...."
                                }
                }
}
```

**This is how I request the response:**

```
interface iLogin
{
   @GET
   RequestResponseLogin loginUser(@Query("user") String user, @Query("pass") String pass);
}

// ....
RequestResponseLogin response = data.loginUser("admin", "abc123");
```

If the login failed, then `public List<String> message;` will be populated with messages from the web server:

```
message[0] = 'Invalid credentials';
message[1] = 'Invalid username';
message[2] = 'Password match correct';
```

But if the web server does not reply anything (success login), than I get an exception by retrofit, because `public List<String> message;` is empty, the web server replied with a simple empty string message and not with a string array. It would work if I change `public List<String> message;` to `public String message;`, but I can't because if the login fails, it must be a string array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Retrofit. Gson is used to deserialize JSON responses by default.

Since your server sends back inconsistent JSON structure, you should use a custom `TypeAdapter` on a `Gson` instance to handle this.

After creating your `Gson` instance (as "`gson`" in this example), you can pass it to Retrofit like this:

```
RestAdapter ra = new RestAdapter.Builder()
    // ... normal stuff ...
    .setConverter(new GsonConverter(gson))
    .build();
```