# 500 Internal Server Error on JHipster Heroku Oauth2 App when accessing via Swift Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, heroku, jhipster, oauth-2.0

I am trying to access a JHipster generated API, which i uploaded on Heroku, via an IOS Swift app. The JHipster app is secured with OAuth2. Basically i want to implement a register functionality where i provide the credentials (email, login and password) in the IOS app and then call the `/api/register` path on the JHipster app to register this user. But  when i make a Swift Alamofire request it gives me a status code of 500 when trying to call  `/api/register`.

My JHipster app at Heroku:
https://j-hipster-test-apiios.herokuapp.com

My Swift Alamofire request:

```
class RegisterViewController: UIViewController {

let parameters: Parameters = [
    "login": "Hello",
    "password": "World",
    "email": "Test@googlemail.com"
 ]


@IBAction func register(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let sessionManager = SessionManager()

    sessionManager.request("https://j-hipster-test-apiios.herokuapp.com/api/register", method: .post, parameters: parameters).validate().responseJSON { response in


        print("----------------------------")
        print(response)
        print("----------------------------")

        sessionManager.session.invalidateAndCancel()
    }

}
```

My Xcode log (The responseValidationFailed error is caused by the .validate() method after the request, because it expects a status code between 200 and 299):

```
 FAILURE: 
         responseValidationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseValidationFailureReason.unacceptableStatusCode(500))
```

My Heroku log:

```
2016-11-04T17:38:36.148902+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/api/register" 
host=j-hipster-test-apiios.herokuapp.com request_id=7a1e1345-a8a5-43f2-abbc-4805037a47ef 
fwd="93.210.40.139" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=13ms status=500 bytes=317
```

So the main question is, why i get a 500 status code when i call the `/api/register` path of my JHipster api?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you get an error 500, it means you have an exception thrown in your jhipster app, so I think you're not looking at the right log. Also does it work when you run your api locally not deployed on Heroku?

Comment: The register functionality works fine when using the JHipster provided client app, but when using curl or Swift request then i get the status code 500 and: `{"message": "error.internalServerError","description": "Internal server error","fieldErrors": null}`, also when requesting it locally.

Comment: run this with dev profile or log aggregation services like ELK to get the exception. Or manipulate the exception translator service to put the message in the errorVM instead of "Internal server error", as it is now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i solved the problem. This was not a JHipster problem but an Alamofire parsing problem. I always made requests with invalid json data because i didn´t validate my credentials Dictionary in my Swift code. If i serialize my json data with `JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters)` i can register a account. For completeness here´s my solution:

```
class RegisterViewController: UIViewController {

@IBAction func register(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let url = NSURL(string: "https://j-hipster-test-apiios.herokuapp.com/api/register")

    var request = URLRequest(url: url as! URL)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    let parameters: Parameters = [

        "activated": true,
        "authorities": [  "ROLE_USER"  ],
        "createdBy": "TestName",
        "createdDate": "2016-11-04T20:42:20.301Z",
        "login": "Hello",
        "password": "World",
        "email": "Test@googlemail.com"
        "firstName": "TestName",
        "id": 0,  
        "langKey": "en",
        "lastModifiedBy": "TestName",
        "lastModifiedDate": "2016-11-04T20:42:20.302Z",
        "lastName": "TestName",


    ]

    request.httpBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters)


    let sessionManager = SessionManager()
    //self.alamofireManager = sessionManager


    sessionManager.request(request).responseJSON { response in

        switch response.response!.statusCode {
        case 201: print("Created")
        case 400: print("Username already in use")
        case 500: print("Error!")
        default: print("Error!")
        }

        sessionManager.session.invalidateAndCancel()
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: @Tobias..Cud u please help me with some more info as I am getting same error while calling api/register in android using retrofit.Its not even working in the jhipster application.

Comment: My mistake was that the JSON data were not valid. So I had to convert the data to a valid format. Have you ever looked at this question which is tackling the same issue but in Android: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19373146/3561941 ?

Comment: It was a different issue.It was due to elasticsearch.Anyways Thanx Tobias.